# Error creating DB2 View: specification ORDER BY, OFFSET, or FETCH clause is invalid

Tags: view, db2

I am attempting what I thought was a very simple view.  It contains one table, and just does an "ORDER BY" so I can sort the output.

I created the view on DB2 LUW using IBM Data Studio.  I used the following statement:

```
  FROM TCIS.JRGS
  ORDER BY JRGSORT ASC, JRGNAME ASC;
```

When I attempt to execute this, I get the following error:

**The specification ORDER BY, OFFSET, or FETCH clause is invalid.. SQLCODE=-20211, SQLSTATE=428FJ, DRIVER=3.69.56**

Is anyone with DB2 experience able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? How do I order a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREATE VIEW](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000935.html) uses [fullselect](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000877.html).
The SQLSTATE you get is described at the latter link. Read it carefully.
Despite the fact, that you can create a view like below, it doesn't guarantee the order of rows, if you use this view without the `order by` clause.

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM TCIS.JRGS
  ORDER BY JRGSORT ASC, JRGNAME ASC
);
```